# Create stored procedure that generates a csv file in a local directory

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs

Bearing in mind, that I am putting together a query in stored processes, I think, I already have the query, but I have searched the internet for the sentence or order to export the query in a .csv file. And some photos tell me that msbk, others bcp, I do not understand well, export the file cn the query, already made.

Just as guidance in the example, which I show you, because I have seen many videos and comments, it doesn't work for me and then how do I run it?

```
USE [BD]
GO 
/*** Consultar campos de uan tabla y exportarlos en un archivo .csv en un 
directorio x****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reports_USER  
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @id int
    declare @nombre_usuario varchar(100)
    declare @username varchar(25)
    declare @nrocedula varchar(15)


    --Consulta a la dbo
     bcp -i Select @id, @nombre_usuario, @username, @nrocedula 
From dbo.Usuarios queryout C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop -S servername -c 
-t"," -T

END


EXEC sp_reports_USER
```

After having the code well, as I would do to test, if it works or not?

Comment: you cannot call bcp from a stored procedure like that.  you could call it with the extended stored procedure xp_cmdshell, if that is allowed on your target server.  Also, I assume that `dbo.Usarios` is a function of some sort?  Can you please post the definition?  In any case, the call to that function is not valid syntax.  Function parameters should be in parentheses.

Comment: This won't help your case.. but please refrain from using sp_ prefix for your stored procedures. SP_ does NOT stand for stored procedure.. they are special procedures reserved by sql server.. and apparently there is a performance and execution difference!